# Any changes to solution yields CefSharp "File Not Found" error

Tags: .net, vb.net, oauth-2.0, cefsharp

I've been updating a project in git as I make improvements and recently have implemented OAuth2 sign in with Google over the less secure, standard method.  I'm using CefSharp to embed the browser window into a windows form.  Here's the parent sub called:

```
    Async Function AuthIt() As Task(Of Boolean)
    If Await RunAuth() Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

And here's the authentication sub:

```
 Public Async Function RunAuth() As Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim state As String = randomDatabase64url(32)
    Dim code_verifier As String = randomDatabase64url(32)
    Dim code_challenge As String = base64urlencodeNoPadding(sha256(code_verifier))
    Dim redirectUri As String = String.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", IPAddress.Loopback, GetRandomUnusedPort())
    output("redirect URI: " + redirectUri)
    Dim http As HttpListener = New HttpListener()
    Dim manager As HttpListenerTimeoutManager = http.TimeoutManager
    manager.HeaderWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    manager.IdleConnection = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    http.Prefixes.Add(redirectUri)
    output("Http redirect is listening...")
    http.Start()

    Dim authRequest As String = String.Format("{0}?access_type=offline&response_type=code&scope={1}&redirect_uri={2}&login_hint={3}&client_id={4}&state={5}&code_challenge={6}&code_challenge_method={7}",
            authEndpoint,
            scopes,
            Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUri),
            EmailUN,
            clientID,
            state,
            code_challenge,
            code_challenge_method)
    Dim embeddedBrowser = New ChromiumWebBrowser(authRequest)
    EmailFunctions.EmailTable.Controls.Add(embeddedBrowser)
    EmailFunctions.Show()

    Dim context = Await http.GetContextAsync()
    Dim response = context.Response
    Dim responseString As String = String.Format("<html><head>SPROCKETS ARE TURNING<br><br></head><body>Signing in and closing this window...</body></html>")
    Dim buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString)
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length
    Dim responseOutput = response.OutputStream
    Dim responseTask As Task = responseOutput.
        WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).
        ContinueWith(Sub(task)
                         responseOutput.Close()
                         http.Stop()
                         output("HTTP listener stopped")
                         Sleep(500)
                     End Sub)
    If context.Request.QueryString.Get("error") IsNot Nothing Then
        output(String.Format("OAuth authorization error: {0}.", context.Request.QueryString.Get("error")))
        Return False
    End If
    If context.Request.QueryString.Get("code") Is Nothing Then
        output("Malformed authorization response. " + context.Request.QueryString.ToString)
        Return False
    End If
    Dim authCode = context.Request.QueryString.Get("code")
    Dim incoming_state = context.Request.QueryString.Get("state")
    If incoming_state <> state Then
        output(String.Format("Received request with invalid state ({0})", incoming_state))
        Return False
    End If
    output("Authorization code: " & authCode)
    Sleep(500)
    If Not Await performCodeExchange(authCode, code_verifier, redirectUri) Then
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

It flags on the following line:

```
        Dim embeddedBrowser = New ChromiumWebBrowser(authRequest)
```

Now here's the weird part.  I pushed to my git repo from my work computer.  I pulled from my home computer.  If I make absolutely no changes I can run the code without issue.  If I make literally any changes at all I get the following exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException   HResult=0x80070002   Message=Could
> not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime, Version=88.2.90.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> Source=CefSharp.Core   StackTrace:    at
> CefSharp.Cef.get_IsInitialized()    at
> CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser.InitializeFieldsAndCefIfRequired()
> at CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser..ctor(String address,
> IRequestContext requestContext)    at
> Altium_Package_Generator.Authorization.VB$StateMachine_14_RunAuth.MoveNext() in C:\Users\rsmith\source\repos\Altium Package Generator\Altium
> Package Generator\Altium Package Generator\Modules\GmailOauth2.vb:line
> 115    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
> at
> Altium_Package_Generator.Authorization.VB$StateMachine_8_AuthIt.MoveNext()
> in C:\Users\rsmith\source\repos\Altium Package Generator\Altium
> Package Generator\Altium Package Generator\Modules\GmailOauth2.vb:line
> 22    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at
> Altium_Package_Generator.MainWindow.VB$StateMachine_9_EmailButton_Click.MoveNext()
> in C:\Users\rsmith\source\repos\Altium Package Generator\Altium
> Package Generator\Altium Package Generator\Forms\Main Window.vb:line
> 178

The only way to "clear" this error and get it to work again is to force a checkout of the git repo branch again.  I have compared the directories before and after the change.  No files appear to be different other than whatever change I've made to the solution.  I've tried changing what a completely unrelated  messagebox says and it will still throw this error.  I've tried adding or deleteing an unrelated app setting and it will still throw this error.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the CefSharp nuget package as well as deleting my bin and obj folders.  Google is no help at this point and I am enough of a noob to not know what the heck is going on.  Can somebody please help me?  I've been stuck on this for over a week.  I'm not looking to use the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker, as it does not allow you to embed the browser in a form.  This method worked flawlessly for over two weeks while I was making other non-OAuth2 related updates.

Comment: How did you get CefSharp  in your project at work in the first place?  Maybe it's just a case of replicating that process at home

Comment: Which Nuget package are you using? How does the minimal example behave? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: I installed the nuget pakage CefSharp.WinForms which also installed CefSharp.Common, cef.redist.x86 and cef.redist.x64 on both machines.  As I said, I was transferring the project back and forth between work and home for two weeks without issue until just over a week ago when I ran into this problem.

Comment: Are you targeting x86, x64 or AnyCpu? Did you happen to commit your bin and obj folders into git?

Comment: Also are you using the older non SDK style project or the newer SDK style project format? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format

Comment: I did commit my bin and obj folders to git, but recognized my error and removed them quite a few commits ago (months ago).  I had been targeting AnyCpu without issue for about a month, then switched over to x64 about a month ago as well without issue.  I've tried changing it back to AnyCpu without successful results.

Comment: I'm not sure about the older or newer SDK version.  I'm using .net 4.7.2 as the target framework, which has remain unchanged throughout the life of the project.

Comment: The question isn't about SDK version,  it's about the project format. Microsoft refers to the newer style of project format as SDK style and the older as non SDK style, those are the terms as detailed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format It's not the clearest naming.

Comment: In your project file add a call to the CefSharpAfterBuildDiagnostic target after build and check the output window in visual studio, there will be extra info that might provide some clues. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms.csproj#L144 for an example. Target looks like https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/88/NuGet/CefSharp.Common.targets#L49